# I am using Local Storage in Javascript.Can anyone tell me how to display the items of local Storage on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

let a = localStorage.setItem('Class','1');

document.write(a);// When I am trying it is unable to print the local Storage on HTML Webpage

Comment: welcome to community, first you need to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . second, `localStorage.setItem()` does not return anything so you don't need to store it in a variable. third, to read the item that you set you simple do this `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test1'))`

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? `setItem` (as the name suggests), _sets_ the item. It doesn't return it, so `a` will be `undefined`. If you want to _get_ an item, use `getItem()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use local storage in Javascript and output the stored elements in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878481/how-to-use-local-storage-in-javascript-and-output-the-stored-elements-in-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

First you set the value for localstorage with setItem, after that value in localStorage, you can get the value with getItem.

```
<script>
  localStorage.setItem('Class','1');
  let a = localStorage.getItem('Class');
  document.write(a);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Renato Sant'Anna for solving my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is like a  variable that persist through the session of broswer.

you need to start to set the localStorage item with (from [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)):

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom')
```

then you can read the localStorage:

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem("myCat");
```

now you can show the localStorage like any other variable in js:
eg

```
document.querySelector('.myDiv').innerHTML = cat
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. LocalStorage has the methods `getItem` to get/read data from it.

Also, I recommend stringifying your data before saving them. Stringifying is really helpful when you are trying to save an array or a large object.

to store/write `localStorage.setItem(item,JSON.stringify(data));`

to read/get `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(item))`

```
 static setItem(item:string,data:any){
        try {
            localStorage.setItem(item,JSON.stringify(data));
            return true;
        }catch (e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }

    static getItem(item:any){
        try {
            const itemResult:any = localStorage.getItem(item);
            return JSON.parse(itemResult);
        }catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```